# How to list all the programs that are available to a given account on a cluster?

Tags: linux, shell, cluster-computing

At my university I am working under a prof as GA. He gave me access to a cluster. Now I want to know the list of tools/softwares I can run using my account. I have no idea what tools are availble on that machine.

Comment: what does "available" mean? e.g. `fdisk` is available for your user, because it is executable for all users. However you cannot re-partition your hard disk, because you don't have permission. you define this available or not? also something like `su`  or `sudo`

Comment: Many cluster administrators use "Environment Modules" to manage applications on a cluster.  If yours do, you can find out what is available using the `module avail` command.  You'll either get a listing including things like "Apps/Mathematica/9.0.1" or the error message "command not found".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n" | while read line; do echo $line; ls $line; done
```

Be prepared for tons of output. You might be better off doing echo $PATH first and looking for interesting-looking directories, or just seeing if tab-completion works (just type 'c', tab, see if it shows 'cat', 'cd', etc).

Really tho, ask the prof for whatever docs you're supposed to have, the tools you're looking for aren't likely to be obvious just from the name of the command.

Comment: this lists things in `$PATH`. files in `$PATH != all the programs that are available to the user's account`

Comment: True, but I figured a find / -executable -type f wasn't going to be very helpful.

Comment: The question for me is not clear. I could not understand what does 'available' mean, and what OP is looking for.

Comment: @Kent by "available" I mean, the ones with execute permission for me.